# Angular innerhtml element failed in capturing click event

Tags: angular, innerhtml

```
        <div style="text-align: left;margin-left: 10px;flex-grow: 1;">
            <div [innerHtml]="secureHtml(control.data.text)" *ngIf="mode!=Mode.MODE_EDITABLE" (click)="handleClick()"></div>
            <app-inline-ckeditor [(text)]="control.data.text" [mode]="mode" *ngIf="control&&mode==Mode.MODE_EDITABLE"></app-inline-ckeditor>
        </div>
```

click on the div with innerHtml doesn't trigger click event

Comment: I don't understand your issue, I think you should provide more details, but it looks for me that there is missing parenthesis   `<div [innerHtml]="html" (click)="handleClick**()**">`

Comment: Include relevant code. `secureHtml`, control definition. You’ve deleted information useful for debugging - namely it’s the innerHtml that is causing the issue.

Comment: secureHtml(html):SafeHtml{

    return this.sanitized.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(html);

  } the html is rendered correctly

Comment: i create a new angular project, the element with innerHtml works correctly with click event. don't know what prevents the event firing from my project.

Answer (score 0):

change your code to this, you are missing brackets replace handleClick with handleClick()

```
<div [innerHtml]="html" (click)="handleClick()">
```

Comment: <div class="subtitle-into-section" >
    <div [innerHtml]="'test'"  (click)="handleClick()">test</div>
    <!-- <app-inline-ckeditor  ></app-inline-ckeditor> -->
</div>
handleClick(){
    console.log("cliked"); 
  }
this is the code I have tested which works fine so you don't have a problem with innerHTML or click event, you have another problem which causing the issue.

Comment: but where is the click event lost? how can i debug it? I couldn't find any information from console.

Comment: 1st of all you try my code if it works then add items one by one, like conditions then additional lines, and see what causes the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I create a new component containing the "to click" element, it works, then add code piece by piece. Finally, the code of two components is the same except component name is different. However, new component works, but old component doesn't work. don't know why, all codes are same, except component name is different.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I finally found how to fix the issue:

This is the incorrect invocation, that renders correctly, but doesn't respond to click:

```
<div [innerHtml]="generateSafeHtml()" (click)="handleClick()"></div>
```

This renders correctly, and responds to click:

```
<div [innerHtml]="safeHtml" (click)="handleClick()"></div>
```